# Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/771F-7614/Android/data/com.example.x/files/x/Photos/x_20200417044051.jpg

Tags: java, android

The application is working in every phone except one. And that phone shows this error. 
In other phones the image path seems like this /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.x/files/x/Photos/x_20200415111325.jpg and works well.

Here is the image creation function

```
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir("Photos");

    File image = new File(storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + photoName);
    try {
        image.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        CustomUtility.showAlert(this, "Image Creation Failed. Please contact administrator", "Error");
    }
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("image path",currentPhotoPath);
    return image;
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be easier for people to assist you if you provide a [mcve] with your question. In your case, you appear to be using `getExternalFilesDirs()` and a directory from [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) and trying to have `FileProvider` serve it. Unfortunately, `FileProvider` does not have a way to do that at the present time. You may need to stick to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) for the time being.

Comment: Yeah i am using getExternalFilesDirs() but what is solution to that problem?

Comment: Write your own `ContentProvider`, perhaps. Or, as I wrote, stick to regular external storage (not removable storage). `FileProvider` presently is not an option for removable storage.